# RegEx to match the opposite of another RegEx

Tags: regex

I was wondering if it's possible to do such a thing with RegEx as the following.

I have this RegEx to check indentation in a text file

```
^( {4})+
```

So from the beginning of each line, count 4 spaces and include consecutive that follow after. This matches like below (I am using underscores to indicate expression matches)

```
0indent
____4indent
____ 5indent
________8indent
________   11indent
```

It isn't very useful because I would prefer to only know the ones that aren't in the RegEx. Is it possible to have a RegEx that can find matches of spaces that have not matched by the current RegEx, along the lines of

```
^( *not matched by ^( {4})+*)
```

To get

```
0indent
    4indent
    _5indent
        8indent
        ___11indent
```

*UPDATE*

@SeamanYen has given me some more insight and I've updated the RegEx to be

```
^( {4})*+( {1,})
```

This is giving a match on Group 1 and Group 2 contains the match I am looking for. This is the best example of what I'm trying to achieve

https://regex101.com/r/Wxv6Hr/1

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you are after, but to identify the leading spaces that are not part of a multiple of 4 spaces, you could try [`^(?: {4})*( +)?`](https://regex101.com/r/AfLJ43/1/) and check the 1st capture group. Or, if supported, you could try [`^(?: {4})*\K *`](https://regex101.com/r/yA9bN6/1)

Comment: There is not "the opposite" of a pattern because when you start to look into it, it becomes more and more meaningless. If you want to match something with `a` somewhere in the middle, then is the opposite with `a` at either end? Is it with no `a` present in the middle? More complex patterns start becoming more and more involved in what would be "the opposite". You *could*, however, find items that *don't* match a pattern. That depends on which tool/programming language you're using but usually it's either a flag or just manually inverting the test (`if(regexMatches)` -> `if(!regexMatches)`)

Comment: You could craft a regex that matches what you want *and* that could be what another regex doesn't match. But it's not a generic solution. You have to specify what you want to actually do.

Comment: @JvdV it sounds like you understand exactly what I'm going for but I'm not sure how to implement your suggestion

Comment: You'll need to explain *where* you are implementing this. Python? JS? Also, what would your expected results look like after you have used your regex?

Comment: Well at the moment I'm just doing it in `https://www.regextester.com/` but it's intended to be used in a vim syntax formatter

Answer (score 1):

```
/^( {4})*+ {1,3}/
```

first add + after quantifier to make search that wont backtrack.  [using the "possessive" quantifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

then search what you want.

plese see this [regexp demo](https://regex101.com/r/SqyYbK/1)

Also works if EOF is reached.

hope this is what you need.

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for, I will update my question to give more information